# What example Bitcoin block has a Namecoin hash in it?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, client, namecoin

I'm looking for an example Bitcoin Block that would have a Namecoin merged-mined Tx in it.

Can anyone direct me to a block that has such a hash?

Comment: That is not exactly how it works. There is no such thing as a merged-mining tx vs a regular tx they are both exactly the same.

Comment: @mschuett I understand that from a Bitcoin perspective, the Tx looks the same, but I want to actually see a Tx that is seen by Namecoin.  I hear the Namecoin Tx can be in many different locations, and I want to understand how that may be the case.

Comment: I think that's very hard. AFAIK there is no Namecoin explorer that shows any merged mining information (the bitcoin block) and you can't reverse the look-up because as @mschuett mentioned it looks just like an ordinary tx in the Bitcoin chain.

Comment: Perhaps if someone will describe the process a namecoin block is encoded in the Bitcoin Tx, I'll search for that Namecoin binary data...

Answer (score 1):

It won't exist. Merged mining only shows up in the auxiliary blockchain (Namecoin), not the parent blockchain (Bitcoin).

Basically, if you find a hash smaller than the target for both, then you submit the block to the Bitcoin network as usual and the Namecoin network as well. If you find a hash smaller than the Namecoin target but larger than the Bitcoin target, then you submit to Namecoin only. Basically the Namecoin blockchain gets stuffed with some junk from the Bitcoin blockchain.

Comment: Perhaps a namecoin ID would be nice.  Is there such a thing as a Namecoin block explorer?  Perhaps I'll build one if not.